# Sonata sonata_type_model_list and inheritance entity

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I have an issue with **sonata_type_model_list** and  inheritance entity.

I have these entities

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Contract
{
    /**
     * @var Provider
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Provider")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="provider_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $provider;
...
}
```

and

```
use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="user_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap(
 *     {
 *     "app_user" = "User",
 *     "provider" = "AppBundle\Entity\Provider",
 *      }
 * )
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user_user", options={"charset"="utf8", "collate"="utf8_bin"})
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
```

and Provider Entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Provider extends User
{
```

I made ContractAdmin

```
 admin.contract:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\ContractAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Contract, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: label.contracts, group: label.contracts }
        calls:
            - [setTranslationDomain, [SonataAdminBundle]]
```

and

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;

class ContractAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
   protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add(
                'provider',
                'sonata_type_model_list',
                [
                    'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Provider',
                ],
```

and when I tried to add a Provider, I got an error

> An Exception was thrown while handling: Impossible to invoke a method
>   ("id") on a null variable in
>   "SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:Form:form_admin_fields.html.twig" at
>   line 59

I want to search and add only provider users to Contract entity.
Sonata cannot find Provider or User entity (NULL) and I cannot figure out how to connect this in ContractAdmin.

What can I do here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My solution  is  EntityType::class and avoid Sonata types. It works fine.

```
class ContractAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
   protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add(
                'provider',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Provider',
                    'choice_label' => 'username',
                    'attr' => array(
                        'data-sonata-select2' => 'true'
                    )
                ],
```

But I do not know why Sonata has troubles. If someone has explanation or better solution please write here.